# Sockets remaining active on abrupt termination of the program

Tags: c, sockets, visual-c++, winsock

I am using the standard WinSock functions for socket communication, Now suppose I create a socket and my program terminates abruptly Is there any chance that the socket remains active ?

I tried a little example, first call to the `socket` API returned `4986`,  after abruptly terminating the executable the second call to the `socket` API returned `4946`

But I still feel that the socket if not closed remains active for sometime.

Please help me clarify my doubt

Comment: You can typically get around this by `setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR)` to allow address reuse on such moribund sockets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On linux machines if you open a socket with a program, then close the program uncleanly i.e. crash it, the socket will remain open. The operating system will clean up these bound sockets in this scenario after a time period has passed (I am not sure how long it is, I assume it specified some where in the OS, it is less than 10 minutes).

http://compgroups.net/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32/bind-error-after-crash-ho/368539
I assume this would mean that the WinSock's do remain open after you crash or forget to close them with your application. I am not sure how windows handles these open sockets but I make inference it would be similar to linux and close them after a time period has elapsed

Comment: So will this affect the packets coming in too.. say in the first call i receive first packet then in the second call (after restart) it will return second packet? or wo;; or will it give the first one again?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Do you mean if the application closes after sending a packet, and then you are wondering if you reopen it if it will send the first packet again, or just skip to the second packet?
I am making the assumption it will send the first packet again since it crashed and doesn't know it sent the first packet already.

Comment: Consider the case where I am the Client. I connect to a server and get some data. Now I abruptly terminate without cleaning. Now i relaunch the executable. Could It be possible that it will pick up the old Socket connection and retrieve the data or it will be a fresh Connection ?
My Doubt is that I get first packet then I restart and I am thinking I am getting the second packet due to the first connection not terminated Could this be true ?

Comment: It would depend on how the server sends packets than. If it sends out the same series of packets when your client connects each time then it will get the first packet again. However if your server sends out new packets every x amount of time, then you will get the second packet. You could try implementing some sort of packet tool like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap  to see what packets are being sent to your clients.